# How to create a Rails 5 model that is actually a Database View created on the go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading this article: https://www.salsify.com/blog/engineering/eager-loading-calculations-database-views-in-rails

I really like the concept of creating a model that is actually a query to another model, in order to create some calculations.

What I'd like to do is currently very simple, for each Tag, I like to get the TagVisits and sum the visits attribute.

The code looks like this:

```
class TagVisitSummary < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :tag

  default_scope { set_from_clause }

  def ==(other)
    self.class == other.class && attributes == other.attributes
  end
  alias :eql? :==

  def hash
    attributes.hash
  end

  private

  def self.set_from_clause
    query = TagVisit.select(:tag_id).group(:tag_id).select('SUM(visits) as total_visits').all
    from("(#{query.to_sql}) AS #{table_name}")
  end

  def self.columns
    cols = [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new('tag_id', nil, :integer)]
    cols << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new("total_visits", nil, :integer)
    cols
  end

end
```

When I paste the SQL generated in `set_from_clause` directly in my Postico, I see exactly the result I'm looking for. Unfortuntaly running `TagVisitSumamry.all` yields no results (and also no error). So, I'm having some doubts whether the `self.columns` method is correct. The example is in Rails 4, I'm using 5. Has there been some changes that require me to change this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, scenic? https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic

It helps with creating database views and materialized views and you can use them as ActiveRecord models.

Comment: I've seen it as an alternative, but in this case I just want a simple view. I think the overhead of creating a materialized view + gem code is not worth the use case here.

Comment: On second look, it seems that scenic also deals with normal views. It might do the trick after all. Thanks.

Comment: @bo-oz Yes, scenic dose allows you to create normal views, materialized view is optional you can opt for. As per size, its maintained by thoughtbot, one of the leading RubyOnRails company out there. Its dependencies are negligible.